# Displaying a single record based on DocID

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with ~900,000 records. I need to display a single record based on DocID using this query. The record is the latest record that got modified by another program.

This piece of query run ~7 seconds:

```
SELECT        TOP 1 t.Register
FROM            PxStats AS s INNER JOIN Therapy AS t ON s.ID = t.ID
WHERE        (s.Date = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND (t.DocID = 1)
ORDER BY s.Time DESC
```

I do not have access to modify the tables design, the table is indexed by ID, but I can't filter the record based on ID because the latest iD is not guaranteed the latest record modified.

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: Not much we can do about performance if the `Date` and `Time` columns are not indexed. That's basically all of the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: @Hosch250 SQL Server 2000

Comment: This is a very simple query, I don't think the query itself is why it is so slow, 7 seconds to me indicates more of a database issue. Do other queries using the same tables take very long also?

Comment: Any query is slow except if I add `ORDER BY ID`

Comment: What's the query execution plan look like?  Execute `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` in a batch before your query.  What's the costliest operation? That's where you should focus your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with SQL 2008 there is a window function that does this nicely.

900,000 records even with lack of index that seems like it should be faster.

I doubt moving the condition into the join will fix the performance but it is worth a try.

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.Register
  FROM PxStats AS s 
 INNER JOIN Therapy AS t 
    ON s.ID = t.ID
   AND s.Date = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
   AND t.DocID = 1
 ORDER BY s.Time DESC;
```

If you can post the query plan.

If you remove the top 1 on average how many records would be returned?

A reach but try

```
declare @today datetime = (select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())));

SELECT TOP 1 t.Register
  FROM PxStats AS s 
 INNER JOIN Therapy AS t 
    ON s.ID = t.ID
   AND s.Date = @today 
   AND t.DocID = 1
 ORDER BY s.Time DESC;
```

Comment: This query is still need ~6 sec, without `TOP 1` the average is 6 sec too, I think I have no option left except add Index on `Date` field

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a workaround by querying last 10000 ID to temporary database, 10000 is 10x the average number of a new record inserted every day, by doing this, I ensure that all record in a given day is returned.

Then after that just query the temporary table using @paparazzo query above.

```
USE MedicalSql;  
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp_PxStats') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp_PxStats;
GO
SELECT TOP 10000 * 
  INTO #Temp_PxStats
  FROM dbo.PxStats
 ORDER BY ID DESC;
GO
SELECT TOP 1 t.Register
  FROM #Temp_PxStats AS s 
 INNER JOIN Therapy AS t 
    ON s.ID = t.ID
   AND s.Date = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
   AND t.DocID = 1
 ORDER BY s.Time DESC;  
GO
```

Comment: If ID is identity and no gaps you could filter directly on that.